# Numpy - Extracting bits from unpacked integer array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `(3,50)` Numpy Array of uint8 that I unpackbits() to form a `(3,400)` array using;
`bit_ry = np.unpackbits(dgSlice_ry, axis=1, bitorder='little')`

I have another array `mask_ry` that I'd like to use as a mask to select specific bits from each 8bit (unpacked integer) - it has a shape `(50,)` corresponding to the original integer array and looks like this;

`array([2, 6, 3, 7, 0, 2, 4, 3 ......])`

When I use `np.take(bit_ry, mask_ry, axis=1)` the mask selects items indexed along the full 400 length axis.

How best do I get my mask to select specific bits from each unpacked integer?  In the mask example above I'm looking to extract bit2 from the first unpacked integer, bit6 from the second, bit3 from the third etc..

Very much appreciate some guidance..

Comment: reahape (3, 400) into (3, 50, 8) and then mask it

Comment: I understand the reshape(3, 50, 8) but how then extract specific single bits from axis=2 using the mask? Do I need to reshape the mask also?

Comment: Got it ...output_ry = bit_ry[row,column]  - Many thanks :)